# jquery calling a function with a variable

Tags: jquery, variables

I'd like to store some functions in variables, something like so:

```
var x = function() {
    //do something here
}
```

how would you then call that function in an onclick for example?

Comment: $(selector).click(x); or $(selector).click(function() { x(); });

Comment: @s4ty post it as answer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a simple google search away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#element').on('click',function(){

   x();

});
```

or

```
$('#element').on('click',x);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5meqt/1/)

Comment: Why did you wrap the function in a FE? `$("#element").click(x)`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Was just about to edit in that :)

Comment: I just wanted to praise you for the fact that you used .on('click' and not one of the many stupid aliases. Ambiguity is far worse than 4 extra characters.

Comment: what about this:  next_slide = function map_part1 ();   
    
$("#next-btn").click(function() {
    next_slide; 
});

Answer (score 1):

```
$(selector).click(x);
```

or

```
$(selector).click(function() { x(); });
```